# How does akka update a mutable state?

Tags: scala, akka, actor-model

I read Akka documentation, but I do not understand:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  private var _state = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case x: Int =>
      if (x != _state) {
        println(s"---------> fail: ${x} and ${_state}")
      }
      _state = x + 1
  }
}


implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  val ref = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "my-actor")
  (0 to 10000).foreach { x =>
    ref ! x
  }
```

I have a `_state` variable which is not `@volatile` and not `atomic` but at the same time `_state` is always correct, if I do changes with `!`-method.
How does Akka protect and update the internal state of actors?

Answer (score 3):

Akka is an implementation of the Actor Model of computation.  One of the (arguably *the*) key guarantees made by the actor model is that an actor only ever processes a single message at a time.  Simply by virtue of having `_state` be private to an actor, you get a concurrency guarantee that's at least as strong as if you had every method of an object be `@synchronized`, with the added bonus of the `!` operation to send a message being non-blocking.

Under the hood, a rough (simplified in a few places, but the broad strokes are accurate) outline of how it works and how the guarantee is enforced is:

- Using the `Props` the `ActorSystem` constructs an instance of `MyActor`, places the only JVM reference to that instance inside an `ActorCell` (I'm told this terminology, as well as that the deep internals of Akka are "the dungeon", is inspired by the early development team for Akka being based in an office in what was previously a jail in Uppsala, Sweden), and keys that `ActorCell` with `my-actor`.  In the meantime (technically this happens after `system.actorOf` has already returned the `ActorRef`), it constructs an `ActorRef` to allow user code to refer to the actor.
- Inside the `ActorCell`, the `receive` method is called and the resulting `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` (which has a type synonym of `Receive`) is saved in a field of the `ActorCell` which corresponds to the actor's behavior.
- The `!` operation on the `ActorRef` (at least for a local `ActorRef`) resolves which dispatcher is responsible for the actor and hands the message to the dispatcher.  The dispatcher then enqueues the message into the mailbox of the `ActorCell` corresponding to `my-actor` (this is done in a thread-safe way).
- If there is no task currently scheduled to process messages from the actor's mailbox, such a task is enqueued to the dispatcher's execution context to dequeue some (configurable) number of messages from the `ActorCell`'s mailbox and process them, one-at-a-time, in a loop.  After that loop, if there are more messages to process, another such task will be enqueued.  Processing a message consists of passing it to the `Receive` stored in the `ActorCell`'s behavior field (this mechanism allows the `context.become` pattern for changing behavior).

It's the last bit that provides the core of the guarantee that only one thread is ever invoking the `Receive` logic.

Comment: yep, I understand that Akka runs messages one by one, but in the same time, these messages can be processed in different threads (dispatchers) but still from one message queue (mailbox), and at this moment (call `receive` method) actors can somehow synchronize internal state. Am I right?

Comment: The actor doesn't synchronize internal state.  An actor always belongs to exactly one dispatcher, which has a thread pool; the dispatcher ensures that's actor's message processing never happens simultaneously on multiple threads.

Comment: yep, I understand this point (about simultaneously), but at the same time, `actor.receive` can be executed in different threads, and how the state should be updated here?

Comment: Any thread that has a reference to the same area of memory (within the bounds of the Java Memory Model) will see the state.  There's no thread-local state (unless you explicitly use thread-local state, of course).

Answer (score -1):

This is the *Classic* model for Akka Actors. If you are just learning actors then you should use *Typed Actors* because that is the supported model going forwards.

With typed actors, the actor system holds the state for each actor, not the actor itself. When an actor needs to process a message the actor system will pass the current state to the actor. The actor will return the new state back to the actor system when it has finished processing the message.

The typed model avoids all synchronisation issues because it does not use any external state, it only uses the state that is passed to it. And it does not modify any external state, it just returns a modified state value.

If you must use Classic actors then you can implement the same model using `context.become` rather than a `var`.

Comment: under `state` I mean some class instance fields, in my example it is `_state`

Comment: @kraik It is bad practice to use class instance fields to hold state for an Actor. For classic actors use `context.become` and for typed actors use the `Behavior`.